# Python: Iterate through list contained within dictionary and perform mathematical operation

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, math

question answerers and python wizards,

I am a weary apprentice seeking some help from a fellow traveller.

```
inventory = {
'gold' : [500, 600, 700, 800],
'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'],
'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']
}
```

I essentially want to iterate through the 'gold' key and add 50 to each value and have that stored [permanently in the original dictionary]. Now, I know how to do it individually...

```
inventory['gold'][0] += 50
inventory['gold'][1] += 50
inventory['gold'][n] += n...
```

but, I'm guessing there must be an easier way to do this task?!!!! Right??!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank y'all in advance!

Comment: `inventory['gold'] = [n + 50 for n in inventory['gold']]`?

Comment: inventory['gold'][n] += n

Comment: Thank you all. Special thanks to @bla - you were totally right! Thanks again, wizards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop.

```
for n in range(len(inventory['gold'])):
    inventory['gold'][n] = inventory['gold'][n] + 50
```

And in a single line

```
inventory['gold'] = [n + 50 for n in inventory['gold']]
```